# K8 DNS not resolving

Tags: kubernetes, dns

My K8 DNS isn't resolving, thus I did follow the debugging steps as [mentioned here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/). As I am new to K8, can someone point me to the issue I am facing? I cant extract any useful information out of the debugging steps.

> cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

> kubectl version

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", 
GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"6b1d87acf3c8253c123756b9e61dac642678305f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:10:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.5", GitCommit:"6b1d87acf3c8253c123756b9e61dac642678305f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-03-18T01:02:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

> kubectl get namespace

```
NAME                   STATUS   AGE
default                Active   7d4h
```

> kubectl get pods dnsutils

```
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dnsutils   1/1     Running   18         18h
```

> kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup kubernetes.default

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

> kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local 
cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

> kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns

```
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   
AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-6vsml   1/1     Running   12  7d4h
coredns-74ff55c5b-mww7g   1/1     Running   12  7d4h
```

> kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns

```
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[INFO] Reloading
[INFO] plugin/health: Going into lameduck mode for 5s
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 3d3f6363f05ccd60e0f885f0eca6c5ff
[INFO] Reloading complete
[INFO] 10.244.0.1:16732 - 59651 "HINFO IN 6307445054232439722.7934820194057826263. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.006053527s
[INFO] 127.0.0.1:58672 - 59651 "HINFO IN 6307445054232439722.7934820194057826263. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.00658948s
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = db32ca3650231d74073ff4cf814959a7
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[INFO] Reloading
[INFO] plugin/health: Going into lameduck mode for 5s
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 3d3f6363f05ccd60e0f885f0eca6c5ff
[INFO] Reloading complete
[INFO] 10.244.0.62:56364 - 32900 "HINFO IN 2808379183970575835.6786373795048579500. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.004922932s
[INFO] 127.0.0.1:48277 - 32900 "HINFO IN 2808379183970575835.6786373795048579500. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.007889024s
[INFO] 10.244.0.62:49106 - 59651 "HINFO IN 6307445054232439722.7934820194057826263. udp 57 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 132 0.005058199s
```

> kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system

```
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
kube-dns              ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   7d4h
monitoring-influxdb   ClusterIP   10.102.51.183   <none>        8086/TCP                 4d21h
```

> kubectl get endpoints kube-dns --namespace=kube-system

```
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                                  AGE
kube-dns   10.244.0.45:53,10.244.0.47:53,10.244.0.45:53 + 3 more...   7d4h
```

> cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

> cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

> cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

It is kinda odd, that both resolv.conf have different values. Also, I have no clue (if I would have to set the DNS IP manually) which IP to choose.

> kubeadm config view

```
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns:
  type: CoreDNS
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.20.5
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
```

**Update**

The dnsutils assigned pod's IP is 10.244.2.20 and not reachable from the single k8 master node.

```
ping 10.244.2.20
```

Comment: Did you installed CNI plugin? What is your node cidr/subnet?

Comment: cidr/subnet `10.244.0.0/16` and flannel/Calico for CNI. I did purge and remove all nodes, re-joined them and then it worked like a charm. I guess I was messing up too much with the firewall-rules. Will document in more detail later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues with my configuration. First off: I did use an incompatible docker version (20.10.5) which isn't supported yet. Hence, I don't know whether this issue also arises when using a supported docker version. However, even with this incompatible docker version, I was able to fix the issue with following steps:

**1. DNS misconfiguration**

I don't know who/what will set the `resolved.conf`'s DNS entries, but my entry was clearly wrong. First, we need to obtain the K8's DNS Cluster-IP Address:

> kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o wide

You will receive all services within all namespaces, including the `kube-dns` Cluster-IP. In my case It looks like following

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
kube-system            kube-dns                                ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   11d   k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system            monitoring-influxdb                     ClusterIP   10.102.51.183    <none>        8086/TCP                 9d    k8s-app=influxdb
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper               ClusterIP   10.110.126.218   <none>        8000/TCP                 11d   k8s-app=dashboard-metrics-scraper
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                    ClusterIP   10.98.164.199    <none>        443/TCP                  11d   k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Use that DNS within your `resolved.conf` file. Where that file is located, depends on your OS. In my case (Ubuntu 20.04) `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

> nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
DNS=10.96.0.10 8.8.8.8 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

**2. Re-Join all nodes**

I did use UFW next to IPTables, which was somehow messing with the configuration. Hence, I did [remove all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60070134/2934290), installed a fresh OS and re-joined the cluster; without activating UFW.

**3. Forward packet policy**

In some versions [docker modifies the iptables](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/issues/799#issuecomment-325581861), such that packets will be dropped in packet-forward scenarios. Override this behaviour on all nodes with:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Just to be sure, also enable ipv4 forwarding with:

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Answer (score -2):

What is the operating system you are using. I was using redhat enterprise Linux and had the similar error.

I have removed everything in /etc/resolv.conf and kept only ip of dns server and it worked.

What is the network policy you are using, for me calico didn't work. I used kube-router with above /etc/resolv.conf setting.

Thanks.

Comment: As stated Ubuntu 20.04. Which IP was left within your resolv.conf? There is also no network policy in-place.

Comment: I have implemented this in my organization, i used our dns server ip, if you are using in your personal cloud or pc, you should use 8.8.8.8.