# OpenShift Origin: Node not ready

Tags: openshift-origin

I appear to have some problem with my installation of OpenShift Origin.

When I get endpoints for the router, I get the following:

```
oc get endpoints --namespace=default --selector=router
NAME          ENDPOINTS   AGE
router-west   <none>      21m
```

Obviously the router should have at least one endpoint.

Im trying to follow the troubleshooting guide on https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/sdn_troubleshooting.html#debugging-the-router however it does not provide assistance in the situation where the router has not endpoints.

When I get my list of nodes, I get:

```
oc get nodes
NAME                         LABELS                                              STATUS     AGE
openshift.hughestech.space   kubernetes.io/hostname=openshift.mydomain.com   NotReady   38d
```

When I describe the node, I get the following:

```
oc describe node openshift.mydomain.com
Name:           openshift.mydomain.com
Labels:         kubernetes.io/hostname=openshift.mydomain.com
CreationTimestamp:  Sat, 06 Feb 2016 21:44:23 +0100
Phase:          
Conditions:
  Type      Status      LastHeartbeatTime           LastTransitionTime          Reason          Message
  ────      ──────      ─────────────────           ──────────────────          ──────          ───────
  Ready     Unknown     Fri, 04 Mar 2016 18:50:39 +0100     Fri, 04 Mar 2016 18:51:21 +0100     NodeStatusUnknown   Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:  88.198.37.183,88.198.37.183
Capacity:
 memory:    24515560Ki
 pods:      40
 cpu:       8
System Info:
 Machine ID:            bafaea4f3c4c4cf6a632047c1d14db1a
 System UUID:           00000000-0000-0000-0000-002421DDE3D7
 Boot ID:           f9febe14-ec61-41d5-b7c3-db2e42f9b452
 Kernel Version:        3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64
 OS Image:          Red Hat Enterprise Linux
 Container Runtime Version: docker://1.8.2-el7
 Kubelet Version:       v1.1.0-origin-1107-g4c8e6f4
 Kube-Proxy Version:        v1.1.0-origin-1107-g4c8e6f4
ExternalID:         openshift.mydomain.com
Non-terminated Pods:        (0 in total)
  Namespace         Name        CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ─────────         ────        ────────────    ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100%, i.e., overcommitted. More info: http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/user-guide/compute-resources.md)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ────────────  ──────────  ─────────────── ─────────────
  0 (0%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
No events.
```

Where have I gone wrong? What do I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: your issue (from other emails) is that your cluster has no nodes to provision pods. If you can't provision pods, then you'll never get any endpoints (or even a working router :)

Comment: Thanks James. Yes, my node is in a state of 'NotReady'. And I'm unsure how to make it ready.

Comment: did you use the advanced installation method (ansible?)

Comment: This solution may help you. [How to restart kubernetes nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40902197/6355684)

Answer (score 4):

Restart the node service and see if that makes a difference in oc get nodes output.

`systemctl restart origin-node`

Unless your node is running you can cannot make a running router pod and resulting in no endpoints.